# find multiple document ascending with limit 1 mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Mongodb.

This is what i have tried

```
var fdevices = mongoose.model('fdevices', dataModelSchema);
var DPMPow = fdevices.findOne({ "Data": { $regex: /DPMPow_P01/i } 
}).sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 }); 
var DPMAmp = fdevices.findOne({ "Data": { $regex: /DPMAmp_P01/i } 
}).sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 });
var DPMkWh = fdevices.findOne({ "Data": { $regex: /DPMkWh_P01/i } 
 }).sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 });
 var MxPeak = fdevices.findOne({ "Data": { $regex: /MxPeak_P01/i } 
 }).sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 });
var MPPeak = fdevices.findOne({ "Data": { $regex: /MPPeak_P01/i } 
}).sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 });

    function getReady() {
     async.series([
   function (callback) {
    DPMPow.exec(function (err, res) {
    callback(null, res);
  })
},
function (callback) {
  DPMAmp.exec(function (err, res) {
    callback(null, res);
  });
},
function (callback) {
  DPMkWh.exec(function (err, res) {
    callback(null, res);
  })

},
function (callback) {
  MxPeak.exec(function (err, res) {
    callback(null, res);
  })

}, function (callback) {
  MPPeak.exec(function (err, res) {
    callback(null, res);
  }) ], function (error, results) {
    console.log(results);
   }
   );
  }
```

above method works for me but its very slow. is there a way i can design single query and get same result instead of queering data one by one. 
In my collection i have single field called  "Data" and my collection contains more than a one million document.

Comment: What you can do is fetch the records with the required pattern at once and then get the latest record by sorting each type of record. This will definitely increase the speed. Use $and & $or

Comment: It will be better if you can give some example, as i said,  i am new to mongodb. @mehta-rohan

Answer (score 0):

```
var fdevices = mongoose.model('fdevices', dataModelSchema); 
var DPMPow = fdevices.find({
$or: [{
    "Data": { $regex: /DPMPow/i }
}, {
    "Data": { $regex: /DPMAmp/i }
}, {
    "Data": { $regex: /DPMkWh/i }
}, {
    "Data": { $regex: /MxPeak/i }
}, {
    "Data": { $regex: /MPPeak/i }
}]
}).sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 });

DPMPow.exec(function(err, res) {
//Now travese thru all the records, when ever you find the unique pattren of 
//data remove all the instances of that particular pattren  
});
```